# Spring 5 + Tomcat standalone - truncated response

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have application written in Spring Boot 2 and REST API. When I run this app on embeded Tomcat server via bootRun gradle task everything is fine.
The problem is that when this application is deployed on standalone Tomcat 8.5 server response is truncated to 8kB. Why is that?

My REST controller:

```
@RestController
public class ApiController {
    public ResponseEntity<Mono<ResultData>> get(String param) {
        // generating data
        return ResponseEntity.ok(Mono.just(ResultData.builder()
            .data(data)
        .build()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I have not extended SpringBootServletInitializer (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) - when you would like to run Spring Boot app as deployable war you have to do this.